# Combining the text with same column name in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about using Pandas module in python to combine two DataFrame.

I have **125 rows and 125 columns** in each DataFrame

In DataFrame 1:

```
     Test1      Test2      Test3      Test4      Test5      Test6 .....
Re1    Pos        Neg        Neg        Neg        Pos        Pos
Re2    Pos        Neg        Pos        Neg        Pos        Neg
Re3    Pos        Neg        Pos        Neg        Pos        Neg
Re4    Pos        Neg        Pos        Neg        Neg        Neg
Re5    Pos        Neg        Pos        Neg        Neg        Neg
.
.
.
```

In DataFrame 2:

```
     Test1      Test2      Test3      Test4      Test5      Test6 .....
Re1    Yel        Blu        Yel        Blu        Blu        Org
Re2    Blu        Blu        Blu        Yel        Blu        Blu
Re3    Org        Blu        Org        Yel        Yel        Blu
Re4    Org        Blu        Org        Yel        Yel        Blu
Re5    Org        Blu        Org        Org        Yel        Blu
.
.
.
```

What I want in the outcome is: 
Combined Dataframe:

```
         Test1          Test2          Test3          Test4          Test5          Test6 .....
Re1    Pos_Yel        Neg_Blu        Neg_Yel        Neg_Blu        Pos_Blu        Pos_Org
Re2    Pos_Blu        Neg_Blu        Pos_Blu        Neg_Yel        Pos_Blu        Neg_Blu
Re3    Pos_Org        Neg_Blu        Pos_Org        Neg_Yel        Pos_Yel        Neg_Blu
Re4    Pos_Org        Neg_Blu        Pos_Org        Neg_Yel        Neg_Yel        Neg_Blu
Re5    Pos_Org        Neg_Blu        Pos_Org        Neg_Org        Neg_Yel        Neg_Blu
.
.
```

It may be a bit easy for you but since I am a beginner in python coding, it will be very helpful if someone can answer my question.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas operators generally align values based on index and column labels. So simply adding the two DataFrames together adds the values element-wise with the correct alignment.
You can also add constant strings, such as `'_'`, to the DataFrame if the values in the DataFrame are all strings and the constant will be broadcasted to all values in the DataFrame:

```
In [32]: dfa + '_' + dfb
Out[32]: 
       Test1    Test2    Test3    Test4    Test5    Test6
Re1  Pos_Yel  Neg_Blu  Neg_Yel  Neg_Blu  Pos_Blu  Pos_Org
Re2  Pos_Blu  Neg_Blu  Pos_Blu  Neg_Yel  Pos_Blu  Neg_Blu
Re3  Pos_Org  Neg_Blu  Pos_Org  Neg_Yel  Pos_Yel  Neg_Blu
Re4  Pos_Org  Neg_Blu  Pos_Org  Neg_Yel  Neg_Yel  Neg_Blu
Re5  Pos_Org  Neg_Blu  Pos_Org  Neg_Org  Neg_Yel  Neg_Blu
```